# A question about the roots of irreducible polynomials.

Tags: polynomials

Let f(x) be a polynomial of at least the second degree, all of whose coefficients are rational numbers and which is irreducible in the field of rational numbers. Let a+bi be any root of the polynomial f(x). If F is the smallest sub-field of the field of rational numbers that contains a+bi, does F always contain a-bi as well?

Comment: " If F is the smallest sub-field of the field of rational numbers that contains a+bi".. No subfield of rationals contain $a+bi$

Comment: In fact, the rationals have **no** proper subfield at all.

Comment: If i am correct, he wanted to say something about **splitting field** but failed to do so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I will assume that the question is really about "the smallest *extension* of $\mathbf{Q}$ containing $a + bi$."

This is false. Consider any irreducible third-degree polynomial $f(x)$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ with one real root $\alpha$ and two complex roots $\beta$ and $\overline{\beta}$. (The irrationality of $\alpha$ is sufficient to assure that $f$ is irreducible.)

Let $K = \mathbf{Q}(\beta)$. If $K$ also contained $\overline{\beta}$, then $K$ would also have to contain the remaining root $\alpha$ (for example, since the roots add up to give the opposite of the $x^2$-coefficient divided by the leading coefficient). But then the polynomial $f(x)$ would split over $K$.

On the other hand, $K = \mathbf{Q}(\beta)$ is isomorphic to $L = \mathbf{Q}(\alpha)$. Yet $f$ can't split over $L$ because $L \subseteq \mathbf{R}$.

Thus $\overline{\beta} \not\in K$.

Comment: $f(X) = X^3 - 2$ is a classic textbook example.

Comment: Yes, I was going to use $x^3 -2$ until I realized that the same argument was valid more generally.

Comment: I must apologize for a gross booboo in my definition of F. I meant to define F as the smallest sub-field of the field of complex numbers that contains a+bi. Many thanks, Tom, for a very nice counter-example. It seems that my question only has a yes answer when f(x) is a quadratic polynomial.